# Using failover URI in ActiveMQ Ajax client

Tags: ajax, activemq-classic, failover

I am using the ajax client to connect to activemq. Can the activemq 
ajax client support the failover transport?  I use an embedded Jetty inside the broker which uses vm transport to forward messages to the broker.

The AJAX client sends messages to the broker using the URL

```
http://localhost:8161/api/amq
```

How can I bring failover support into this.

FWIW I am using amq.js.

Thanks,
Bhanu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following getting and setter functions to the end of the object returned in the amq.js file (i.e. after the testPollHandler function):

```
setUri: function(newUri) {
    uri = newUri;
},
getUri: function() {
    return uri;
}
```

Then do something like this to switch to the next server if a connection could not be established:

```
var ACTIVEMQ_SERVERS = ["http://server1:8161/ajax/amq","http://server2:8161/ajax/amq"];
var amq = org.activemq.Amq;

function connectStatusHandler(connected) {
    if (!connected) {     
        var index = _.indexOf(ACTIVEMQ_SERVERS, amq.getUri());
        var newIndex = (index + 1) % ACTIVEMQ_SERVERS.length;
        var uri = ACTIVEMQ_SERVERS[newIndex];
        amq.setUri(uri);

        if (window.console) {
            console.log("Lost connection. Attempting next server: " + uri);
        }
    }
}

amq.init({
    uri: ACTIVEMQ_SERVERS[0],
    logging: true,
    timeout: 20,
    connectStatusHandler: connectStatusHandler,
    logging: true
});
```

You'll also need CORS enabled in the Jetty server that hosts the AjaxServlet if you are to establish connections across servers. To do that, enable the built in Jetty CORS filter with the following configuration in the web.xml file:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
      <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>allowedMethods</param-name>
      <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>allowedHeaders</param-name>
      <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/amq/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

The failover transport is for OpenWire connections. For HTTP you need some other fail over mechanism, such as a load balancer that is aware of which nodes are online or not.

Comment: Hmm, we have load balancer support but we use it mostly for switching between DR and normal mode. Was wondering if there was an easy way for this.

Comment: Well, there is no client side support in amq.js for failover. If you don't want to switch to doing the setup some other way you need to rely on a HTTP failover mechanism such as a Load balancer (could even be a software load balancer using Nginx or similar)